# SQL query filter down to only applicable rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, where-clause

How would I select a query like this? I am a bit confused because this would return nothing since any of the rows do not fulfill any of the "where clauses"..

What I would like is the answer to the query to produce the count of 1. And that the productId is "1"... Thanks for help!

```
SELECT productId where carId=12 and objectiveId=15 and locationId=11

+----+-----------+------------+-------------+------------+
| id | productId | carId      | objectiveId | locationId |
+----+-----------+------------+-------------+------------+
|  1 |         1 |         12 |           0 |          0 |
|  2 |         1 |          0 |          15 |          0 |
|  3 |         1 |          0 |           0 |         11 |
|  4 |         2 |         11 |           0 |          0 |
|  5 |         2 |          0 |          10 |          0 |
|  6 |         2 |          0 |           0 |         14 |
+----+-----------+------------+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur Please avoid promoting your answer here.  Stack Overflow already sends a notification to the OP every time a new answer is given.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen got it now. Will revise my answer shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach here would be to aggregate by product and then assert the presence of the various IDs:

```sql
SELECT productId
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY productId
HAVING SUM(carId = 12) > 0 AND SUM(objectiveId = 15) > 0 AND SUM(locationId = 11) > 0;
```

For an explanation to the above, the `HAVING` clause evaluates *after* the `GROUP BY` aggregation has taken place.  That is, whatever logic which you see in the `HAVING` clause deals with the groups of records for each product (and *not* the individual product records themselves).  The expression `SUM(carId = 12)` basically counts the number of times for which `cardId = 12`.  You want this condition to be true at least once, for each matching product (as well as the other two conditions).

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems to do exactly what I am looking for. But is there a chance you could explain the HAVING and SUM? Trying to understand exactly what happens here.. ?

Comment: Thanks Tim! Do you know why the other answer this "SELECT distinct productId from mytable where carId=12 or objectiveId=15 or locationId=11" doesn't work? In my mind it should...

Comment: @MarcusSilverman Coincidentally, it _does_ happen to work for your current data set.  The problem is that it would match any product matching _any_ of the three conditions, not all three of them.  To check all 3 at once, you basically need aggregation logic (you can do it with exists logic as well, but it's still really a form of aggregation).

Answer (score 0):

Use or instead of and with Distinct to select unique productid.

```
SELECT distinct productId from mytable where carId=12 or objectiveId=15 or locationId=11
```

**Example with link:**

> ```
> create table mytable ( id int , productId int, carId int, objectiveId int, locationId int);
>
> insert into mytable value( 1 ,1 ,12 ,  0 , 0 );
> insert into mytable value( 2 ,1 , 0 , 15 , 0 );
> insert into mytable value( 3 ,1 , 0 ,  0 ,11 );
> insert into mytable value( 4 ,2 ,11 ,  0 , 0 );
> insert into mytable value( 5 ,2 , 0 , 10 , 0 );
> insert into mytable value( 6 ,2 , 0 ,  0 ,14 );
> ```

**Query:**

> ```
> SELECT distinct productId from mytable where carId=12 or objectiveId=15 or locationId=11
> ```

> | productId |
> | --- |
> | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=df1b1279e00171b608ed865e8479a02a)*

Comment: Thank you very much. This works as as well, but when I have another productId that also has same location id as another productId, it tends to display both and not fulfill the criteria of all three..? If you see what I mean..

Comment: Got it now. In that case @Tim Biegeleisen answered in a smart way. Can't think of better option. Best wishes.